# Help on how to link this current script to a radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

As the title states I need some help on how to link this Jquery script for a show / hide effect to a radio button selection.

HTML

```
<tr>
<td><input type="radio" name="es_custom_reg" value="Y" /></td>
<td>Yes</td>
<td><input type="radio" name="es_custom_reg" value="N" /></td>
<td>No</td>
</tr>
```

Javascript

```
<script src="scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){

   $('#slide').hide();

      $('a').click(function(){

   $('#slide').show('slow');

   });

   $('a#close').click(function(){
     $('#slide').hide('slow');
  })

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. In the javascript snippet you provided none of the selectors are found in your HTML snippet. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#slide').hide();
    $(':radio[name=es_custom_reg]').click(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if (value === 'Y') {
            $('#slide').show('slow');
        } else if (value === 'N') {
            $('#slide').hide('slow');
        }
    });
});
```

And [here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ex56L/1/).

Answer (score 1):

use selector

jQuery("input[name='es_custom_reg']") this will give you reference to both the radio buttons. Use each.

jQuery("input[name='es_custom_reg']").each  to loop through these two selections and then on the condition of .html()=='yes' execute your code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: To clarify, the javascript function is currently attached to a link on another page which creates the effect perfectly, what I want to do is take this javascript snippet and edit it to respond to the radio button on the html found on this page.